# Delete from a database

Tags: asp.net, linq, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net, I am barely learning, and I want to delete data from a postgres DB.
I have a list displayed in a view, which has an action to remove, but not how to do it.
Who can help me?

Comment: Please write at least some of your code here.....

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with PostgreSQL, but the common concept is the same.

> 1). register a provider to Database and get the connection from it.
>
> 2). open that connection and create a `command/statement` object in
>   some case.
>
> 3). send your SQL statement to Database via `command/statement` object
>   you got in step 2.
>
> 4). deal with the result or returns from step 3.
>
> 5). release the resources you opened above (such as close database
>   connections).

**Why not grasping this chance to learn how to work with PostgreSQL and C# from the tutorials as following,**

1. http://blog.m6.net/learn-how-to-integrate-postgresql-with-asp-net-application/ (ASP.NET)
2. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/john_charles/using-postgresql-from-microsoft-net/ (Pure C#)

Good luck with your learning :-)